# logback-classic does not log Java Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, logging, logback

I can confirm that my `logback.xml` file (placed in `src/main/resources`) is correctly picked up, and used by the Java executable. I configured it to log everything at `INFO` level or higher to a `FILE` and to `STDOUT`. Everything works as expected (logging is output to both places), except that Exceptions are *only* logged to `STDOUT`, but not to the `FILE`. What's missing in my `logback.xml`?

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>./logs/batch.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I'm facing that right now.